# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программа через библиотеку Telethon, получает данные по номеру телефона из текстового файла, и выводит их на экран.
В текстовом файле номера вида:
+79xxxxxxx
+79xxxxxxx

```
pop = open('1.txt', "r+")
content = pop.readline()
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
contact_info = client.get_entity(content)
a = contact_info.first_name
b = contact_info.last_name
c = contact_info.username
print ('Имя',a)
print ('Фамилия',b)
print ('Логин',c)
```

Если указано pop.readline(), программа считывает только первый номер из файла, и выводит информацию о нём. Это будет логично. Но если изменить

```
content = pop.readline()
на
content = pop.readlines() # чтение всех строк
```

Я получаю такую ошибку

```
a = contact_info.first_name
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'first_name'
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у вас в contact_info не какой-то объект с полями first_name, last_name, username, а просто список. Выведите contact_info через print, и посмотрите что там.

Comment: Кстати, ваш же комментарий в строке `content = pop.readlines() # чтение всех строк` предполагает, что считывается не один элемент, а несколько, т.е. список.